# Mixed effects model to examine relationship between two variables changing over time

Tags: mixed-model

I have people that have two measures taken (measure A and measure B);  they have these taken at baseline and after an intervention. I want to know if the change in one measure after the intervention is related to the change in the other measure.

I could just correlate the change scores for the two variables but I was hoping to fit a mixed model so as to not need to discard subjects where some data is missing. Most individuals have one observation of both measures taken before and one observation of both measures taken after the intervention, but for some the measures may be missing before or after.

How would I fit this in a mixed level model?

Comment: Can you say a bit more? Do you have one observation of each measure before and one after for each subject?

Comment: @BenBolker I have edited the question, most subjects have one observation of each measure before and after but for some data is missing)